# ASP.NET Core OIDC Not Working with Multiple Proxies

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, azure-api-management

I am new to MSAL and OIDC, so apologies ahead of time if I misspeak.

I'm running an ASP.NET Core 6.0 application that exposes a web page for employees to access.  This application is most often deployed to on-prem client servers, so it can potentially sit behind one or more load balancers or other proxies depending on the client's network.

The employee web page uses OIDC to challenge requests and redirect users to a Microsoft login, after which they are navigated back to the auth redirect URL and allowed access to the page.  This seems to work without issue when my integration is sitting behind a single proxy, but whenever there is more than one proxy, several issues present themselves that prevent successful authorization.

In my test setup, I am using Azure API Management Services and ngrok in concert to test against a locally-running instance of my web application.  API Management Services is set to forward requests to ngrok, which forwards requests to my application on localhost.

I am using ForwardedHeaderMiddleware in Startup.cs with a few options that are different from the default:

```cs
// In ConfigureServices()
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All;
    options.ForwardLimit = null;
    options.RequireHeaderSymmetry = false;
});

// In Configure()
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

With this setup, if I make a request to my web page through API Management (e.g. https://myorg.azure-api.net/myApiPath/myPage), I will get a "Correlation Failed" error once the request is redirected back to my app.  This is because the *host* of the request is "myorg.azure-api.net" and the *path* is "/myPage", so those are set as the Domain and Path of the Nonce and Correlation cookies respectively.  This means that when my request is eventually redirected back through API Management to my app (e.g. https://myorg.azure-api.net/myApiPath/signin-oidc), the correlation and nonce cookies are filtered out of the response because they do not match the path of the redirected request.  Their path is "/myPage", but the redirected request's path is "/myApiPath/myPage".

I tried to fix this by manually setting the Path of those cookies to "/":

```cs
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.NonceCookie.Path = options.CorrelationCookie.Path = "/";
});
```

This prevents the cookies from being filtered out of the request once it is redirected back to my app, but I am presented with a different error:

> AADSTS500112: The reply address 'https://123456789.ngrok.io/signin-oidc' does not match the reply address 'https://myorg.azure-api.net/myApiPath/signin-oidc' provided when requesting Authorization code.

This makes it seem like ASP.NET Core is expecting the Host of the redirected request to match the host of the redirect URI provided in the initial challenge.  I am not sure how that would be possible in a setup with multiple proxies.  I tried modifying some SameSite policies from here, but that only resulted in having those cookies filtered out again by Chrome for various reasons.

I suppose my question is two-fold.

- What am I doing wrong here?  Am I missing some configuration that would allow this passthrough to work?
- Am I overcomplicating this setup?  It seems to me that it's not all that uncommon for an application to be running behind multiple proxies, so I feel like there must be a better way to handle this.  Setting the Path of the Nonce and Correlation cookies to "/" feels like a workaround to a problem, not the solution, and I'm surprised that I have to do so much manual fiddling just to get working behind two proxies.

Comment: The `AADSTS500112` error is caused by the inconsistency between your redirect Url and the one set in Azure. You can see `redirect_uri=xxx` in the Url of the login page, you can try to copy this Url into Azure.

Comment: @Chen The redirect Url I am using is specified in the AAD app registration.  You might be thinking of `AADSTS50011`: "The redirect URI <Redirect URI> specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application <GUID>. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal."